# Intellij : Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module, when running a Junit Test case

Tags: java, groovy, junit4

I am running a Junit Test case in Intellij and i get the "Run Test Case" option as well. But when i run it, i get a error :

```
Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'Module-Name'
```

The below is a blank test case written that i expect atleast to run.

```
import org.junit.Test

class HttpInteractTest {
@Test
void testGetDataFromHttpDomainEndpoint() {        
}
void testGetData() {
}
```

}

Not Sure why did the IDE suddenly start complaining about Groovy. I dont have any groovy code or connection!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the default Testing library to Junit 4/5. There is a possibility that the default testing library got changed to Groovy.
Create Test -> Testing Library -> JUnit5